# sql statement not working getting errors

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am having some trouble getting a statement to run,  I am looking for the total credits of each student and the student ID.

I have written:

```
select student.ID,sum (course.credits)
from (student natural join takes),course 
where takes.course_id=course.course_id
group by student.ID
```

when I run this I get the following error:
column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier

my tables are

```
create table student
(ID             varchar(5),
 name           varchar(20) not null,
 dept_name      varchar(20), 
 tot_cred       numeric(3,0) check (tot_cred >= 0),
 primary key (ID),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department
    on delete set null

create table takes
(ID              varchar(5), 
 course_id           varchar(8),
 sec_id              varchar(8), 
 semester            varchar(6),
 year                numeric(4,0),
 grade                   varchar(2),
 primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
 foreign key (course_id,sec_id, semester, year) references section
    on delete cascade,
 foreign key (ID) references student
    on delete cascade
```

I am not sure what the problem is. when I run this statement it works

```
select name, sum(course.credits)
from (student natural join takes),course 
where ID=1000 and takes.course_id=course.course_id
group by name
```

if you can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.. thank you

Comment: Why not use the more normal form of joins with the ON clause?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Oracle <> MySQL!!!

Comment: You have this tagged for two database systems. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: hi  I am using SQL developer  sorry to query with

Answer (score 1):

`NATURAL JOIN` is not recommended and can lead to subtle unintended bugs, particularly when tables are modified later. Use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
select name, sum(c.credits)
  from student s
  inner join takes t
    ON t.ID = s.ID
  inner join course c
    ON c.COURSE_ID = t.COURSE_ID
  where s.ID = 1000
  group by name
```

Best of luck.

Comment: The inner join works great thank you now if I can just the other statement to work I will be in great shape.  I tried changing it as suggested and still will not work

Comment: What does "still will not work" mean? You don't get the expected results? If so, what does your test data look like, what results did you expect, and what did you get? Did you get an error? If so, what is the *exact text* of the error? Please edit your question and include the above information. And while you're in there, please include the definition of the `course` table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `from` clause is just wrong with regard to how you use your brackets. Just use an explicit `join` clause for all your joins and you should be OK:

```
SELECT       student.ID, SUM(course.credits)
FROM         student
NATURAL JOIN takes
NATURAL JOIN course 
GROUP BY     student.ID
```

Comment: hey thank you for the advice. I made the changes that's you have suggested and I am getting the same error::                                                                                                    "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"